# Count Unique Values found in all columns PL/SQL in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

The Problem statement: User wishes to invoke a procedure which populates a table listing the column names and the count of unique values found.

I'm not new to SQL but new to Oracle, i have been trying to write a procedure for the above problem, learning that in Oracle you can perform loops. The following code runs with no error, but actually does nothing, not even populate the table.

the proc is run by using

```
EXEC PRC_UNIQUE_COUNTS('mychema.mytable');
```

allowing the user to run this over a table of their choosing, it should truncate the table before it inserts the data again.

could do with some pointers to see when i'm going wrong, as the log is giving me

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

code is as follows

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_UNIQUE_COUNTS (
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2
) IS
    v_column_name  VARCHAR2(128);
    v_unique_count NUMBER;
    v_sql          VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   -- Truncate the output table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE myschema.TBL_UNIQUE_COUNTS';
    FOR t IN (
        SELECT
            column_name
        FROM
            all_tab_columns
        WHERE
            table_name = upper(p_table_name)
        ORDER BY
            column_id
    ) LOOP
        v_column_name := t.column_name;
      
      -- Dynamic SQL to get the count of unique values in the column
        v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT '
                 || v_column_name
                 || ') FROM '
                 || p_table_name;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
        INTO v_unique_count;
      
      -- Insert the result into the output table
        INSERT INTO myschema.tbl_unique_counts (
            col_name,
            unique_count
        ) VALUES (
            v_column_name,
            v_unique_count
        );

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;  -- Commit the transaction
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('An error occurred: ' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

right now, wether its best to write this into a table is not the main issue, my issues is i cant find out WHY its doing what i want, there is no log as such as there i no error.

any help would be great

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, you can do that the way you posted. However, consider a different approach: data dictionary itself.

You should gather statistics regularly (e.g. daily) anyway, so - if users aren't interested in current distinct values ("right now!"), you could query `user_tab_columns` and check its `num_distinct` column value.

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCOTT', 'EMP');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select column_name, num_distinct
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name = 'EMP';

COLUMN_NAME     NUM_DISTINCT
--------------- ------------
EMPNO                     14
ENAME                     14
JOB                        5
MGR                        6
HIREDATE                  13
SAL                       12
COMM                       4
DEPTNO                     3

8 rows selected.
```

Is that really so?

```
SQL> select count(distinct job) cnt_job,
  2         count(distinct mgr) cnt_mgr,
  3         count(distinct deptno) cnt_dept
  4  from emp;

   CNT_JOB    CNT_MGR   CNT_DEPT
---------- ---------- ----------
         5          6          3

SQL>
```

Comment: Statistics are gathered regularly automatically by Oracle. In most cases there is no need to gather them manually.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not sure we can know what happens in "most cases", but in the many large systems I have worked on the default overnight stats process is either disabled or unreliable (as it usually cannot complete within the allocated time window), and in any case as data is continually loaded during the day an overnight stats job would be insufficient even if it completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
WHERE table_name = upper(p_table_name)
```

will evaluate to

```
WHERE table_name = 'MYCHEMA.MYTABLE'
```

However, the table name would be `MYTABLE`, not `MYCHEMA.MYTABLE`.

And when you select from `all_tab_columns`, then you should also consider the OWNER, otherwise you may select the wrong table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `'mychema.mytable'` as the schema's name is `myschema` and the table's name is `mytable` (not `mychema.mytable`).

Either:

- Only pass `'mytable'` and query the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` view if you are running the procedure from the same schema; or
- Modify your procedure to take two arguments `p_owner` and `p_table_name` and pass them separately.

  Then you can look for:

  ```sql
  SELECT column_name
  FROM   all_tab_columns
  WHERE  table_name = UPPER(p_table_name)
  AND    owner      = UPPER(p_owner)
  ORDER BY column_id
  ```

  and

  ```sql
  v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ' || v_column_name || ')'
           || ' FROM ' || p_owner || '.' || p_table_name;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code just a bit adjusted:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_UNIQUE_COUNTS (p_table_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
    v_column_name  VARCHAR2(128);
    v_unique_count NUMBER;
    v_sql          VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   -- Truncate the output table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_UNIQUE_COUNTS';
    FOR t IN (  SELECT    column_name
                FROM      all_tab_columns
                WHERE     table_name = upper(p_table_name)
                ORDER BY  column_id   ) LOOP
        v_column_name := t.column_name;

      -- Dynamic SQL to get the count of unique values in the column
        v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ' || v_column_name  || ') ' || Chr(10) || 
                 'FROM ' || p_table_name;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_unique_count;

      -- Insert the result into the output table
        INSERT INTO tbl_unique_counts ( column_name, unique_count ) 
        VALUES ( v_column_name, v_unique_count );
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;  -- Commit the transaction
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('An error occurred: ' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

Test on one of my tables...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    PRC_UNIQUE_COUNTS('LOG_TRANSLATIONS');
END;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Cheking the table ...

```sql
Select * From TBL_UNIQUE_COUNTS;
/*    R e s u l t  :
COLUMN_NAME                                                      UNIQUE_COUNT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ------------
ID                                                                      55832
DATE_TIME                                                               12020
REQ_TEXT                                                                42673
REQ_LANG                                                                    8
REQ_LENGTH                                                                169
STATUS                                                                      3
RESP                                                                    42289   */
```